# Apache POI : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.util.StringUtil.hasMultibyte

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

when I run this code :

```
XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(colIdx);
cell.setCellFormula(formula); //formula value "IFERROR(H4/$G4,"-")"
```

I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.util.StringUtil.hasMultibyte(Ljava/lang/String;)
```

Can someone help me?

I'm using Apache POI 3.8 with Java SE 6

Thanks.

Comment: The issue might be due to some different version of POI being referred.

Comment: Check whether multiple versions of poi jars in your classpath

Comment: Yes, there's another POI library in the classpath! Thanks!

Comment: Did you [try following the advice in the Apache POI FAQ](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006)? Also, why are you using such an old version of POI?

Comment: @Gagravarr in addition to that, why such an old version of Java as well?